# How to update TortoiseSVN over the network?

Tags: svn, networking, tortoisesvn

I want to import my project from the repository that is on another computer on the network. I have TortoiseSVN installed. I right click the folder -> SVN Check out -> Which prompts me for repository.

My repository exist on my system in c:\repositary\myprojects\trunk\project1.

How to I access from remote PC. On Local machine I use this syntax.

- **file:///**c:/repositary/myprojects/trunk/project1 (*three* forward slashes)

The [documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html) says I should use this syntax.

- **file://servername**/repositary/myprojects/trunk/project1 (*two* forward slashes + servername).

But this does not work. What do I have to do to make it work? Do I need to share that folder? Do I have to mention c:\ drive in the server path?

Want to mention, the repository is on my computer (Windows XP), and I want to access it over a virtual machine on another computer on the network.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on superuser...as it isn't quite about programming.

Comment: First off, don't use the file:// protocol. It is not recommended. It is easy to set up an svn server.

Comment: only programmers will use this thing :) and I am sure a lot of people have answer to this question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a URL like this, and it works fine:

```
file://MYPC-NAME/repositories/All_CODE/trunk/Project1
```

Notice that it may not work all the time.

I had one confusing issue. What if your hard drive is partitioned into C, D and E Drive. Well in that case just use your PC name, followed by the folder that you have shared that contains the repositories.

Answer (score 2):

You <strike>can't</strike> shouldn't use `file://` protocol for over-the-network SVN access. See [this table](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc.tbl-1) from SVN book.

Why don't you [setup an SVN server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve)? You don't have to set it up using Apache, instead, just use plain `svnserve`

Comment: thanks but `file://` actually did work for me. No need to provide c:/ in path, I did share the c:\repository folder just if it is needed. If I dont use `file://`, I get error "not correct url"

Comment: @Dave: Read this answer again. It's all in there: "You can't use `file://` protocol for over-the-network SVN access." I think that's pretty straight and plain. "...setup an SVN server..." So you can't use another protocol without setting up a server. You will have to put some minimal effort into reading this. Also, see @crashmstr's comment to your question. `file://` does have its disadvantages. That you haven't run into them doesn't matter.

Comment: Unfortunately, you CAN use file:// on a network when you have a network share. You really SHOULDN'T. [recommendations](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.recommendations)

Comment: Agreed, not a good practice. But I am a newbie and have a small project that I am testing on multiple machines. If it works now, sounds good to me :) May be in future I can setup the server. I totally understand that.