# Checkout SVN repository from a network

Tags: svn, windows-xp, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2003

I asked a similar question before *[How to update TortoiseSVN over the network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752009/how-to-update-svn-tortoise-over-the-network)*. At that time I was using a VM copy of the server, and the solution I listed worked. This time I am using the actual server and I have trouble checkout out my repository.

```
Unable to open an ra_local session to URL 
Unable to open repository 'file://REMOTE-PC/repositories/MyApps/trunk/App1' 
Can't open file '\\REMOTE-PC\repositories\MyApps\trunk\App1\format': Logon 
failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

My questions are

1. Do I need special permission on the folder on the server so I can successfully checkout the repository?
2. [The documentation here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc.tbl-1) points out which protocol to use where? I was using this before on VM which worked

   file://REMOTE-PC/repositories/MyApps/trunk/App1

What should I be using?

```
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| file:///   | Direct repository access (on local disk)                     |
| http://    | Access via WebDAV protocol to Subversion-aware Apache server |
| https://   | Same as http://, but with SSL encryption.                    |
| svn://     | Access via custom protocol to an svnserve server             |
| svn+ssh:// | Same as svn://, but through an SSH tunnel.                   |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What it worked before and does not work now? Please address both the questions.

I also want to mention, If I want to access my PC (where repository are) from server (I am using remote desktop), I have to enter username and password. Do I have to supply these in SVN command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use the `file://` protocol. Never, never, never. Well, there are times when it can be used, but it should only be if all the following are true:

- You are the only one using the repository.
- The repository is sitting on your system.
- You are trying Subversion out.

If your repository sits on a remote system. Do not use `file://`. If this is a public repository, you do not use `file://`. The `svnserve` Subversion server process is extremely easy to setup and use. And, it's fast, and it avoids all the problems and errors associated with accessing the repository directly. In fact, on my private repository that sits on my system, I use `svnserve`.

---

There are at least a dozen errors that could crop up to cause the problems you point to. There are permissions needed for the server, on modern Windows system, there could be UAC issues even if you're logged in as an administrator. It simply is asking for trouble.

Take a look at the documentation for setting up the [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html). The biggest issue you will run into is making sure that your IT department isn't blocking port 3690.

Run the svnserve process on the remote server and make sure that the server process has complete ownership and all permission on all the files in the repository.

There are a couple of gotchas about the `svnserve` process that doesn't allow it to run out of the box:

- **Edit the `conf/svnserve.conf` file**: This file is pretty good by default. However, the default password file is commented out. Remove the `#` you see in front of the line `password-db = passed`. I'm not sure why this isn't the default. You can also set the name of the `realm` while you're at it. That's not necessary.
- **Edit the `passwd` file**: You need to set the user name and password for each user. Just follow the example.

And, then run `svnserve` and now you can access your repository via:

```
$ svn ls svn://REMOTE-PC/MyApps/trunk/App1
```

This is easy to do (the whole thing can be setup in minutes) and will eliminate all of your problems.

Comment: First of all, Great answer and well explained. Some questions though. I usually need my login name when I access my PC from server (Rep on my PC). SVN does not require these login? 2) I have svnserve.conf, authz, and passwd. (passed is probably a type?). Thank you

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter - It wasn't necessarily a typo as an autocorrect _correction_. I type `passwd` and it corrected it as `passed`, which really _passes_ me off.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter - You will need some sort of login for the repository server just to get everything setup. Once `svnserve` is up and running, you don't need a Windows user account on the server to use Subversion. In fact, it's better not to. That way, a user can't munge up the repository. The svn accounts and password are in the `passwd` file. The user's default account name comes from the user's environment. If the user logged in as _dave_, Subversion will take it as the name of the Subversion account. Otherwise, the user can use the `--username` parameter to specify one.

Comment: @DavidW. Using SVN over file:/// is not the most optimal way but it's not going to break your SVN repository even if the network fails. SVN creates a transaction then promote it to a revision once completed. Worst case you'll end up with an uncommitted transaction and your repository wil still be fully functionnal (at least in 2015). To clean up these failed transactions, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.diskspace.deadtxns

Comment: @formix The main job of a version control system is to protect the safety of the repository. To use `file://`, you must give everyone who will use it write access to the repository itself. Any user can manually edit the files, or delete the repo. Also, there can be issues with network drives and guaranteeing writes. The `svn` command on the remote system cannot always verify that the write actually took place in some network file systems. This is especially true with older implementations of `nfs`.

Comment: @DavidW. You are absolutely right about the write access to the repository. People who can access the repository could get to the folder and do whatever they like with it. But its the same issue with an svn+ssh access when users can login to the ssh server. Having a daily backup system is very important. Concerning the network failure risk, the only difference between a service and a direct nfs access is that the service will cleanup the unpromoted transaction while the direct nfs access will leave this transaction file. Read the first paragraph from the SVN doc. link in my previous post.

Comment: Awesome answer. I was looking for a way to checkout from my home Synology disk storage without mounting it as a network drive, and when I found this answer I thought, "Oh, that's going to be a real trouble installing `svnserve` on it". And it turned out it was just a matter of a few clicks in the web interface (which truly amazed me as I never expected to find SVN in a home NAS package manager repository). Got everything up and running in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

With Subversion, your libraries have strict requirements on the files being manipulated to store "the repository".  SMB services / Windows shares / Samba doesn't meet those requirements.

You should never hide the network from subversion by using the `file://` protocol across a network share.  This means that network failures and outages don't trigger subversion's awareness that a change might not be properly stored.  Depending on the change and circumstance, this can have really bad effects on your repository.

If you are using a remote repository, use one of the network-aware protocols.  They have the proper code to detect and capture network outages and will not be confused into mis-reporting something was saved in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Check read/write permissions on this path:

```
\\REMOTE-PC\repositories\MyApps\trunk\App1
```

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention. I am logged in as Administrator.